# Purchasing a6000: but what lens to buy?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, sony

I'm not a professional by any means but I currently own a Rebel t3 but looking to get a good camera that's much smaller as we often times leave the Rebel behind since it is so large. I think I've settled on the Sony a6000 but I'm trying to determine what to do lens-wise. I don't want to make a huge investment up front so I'll probably only go with one lens for now (either the kit lens or buy the body and one other lens).

My question is that most of our photography involves pictures of our children and many sports activities (baseball, gymnastics, skiing). Would I be best served by just getting the kit lens right now, or is there 1 specific lens that would get me by for awhile and allow me to take good photos of the kids in their activities?

Comment: I'm sure you'll be happy with the Sony A6000. This question on the other hand is not a great fit for PhotoSE. A good question is one for which can be given one correct answer. A lens recommendation is not such question. Our chat room is better place to ask this ;)

Comment: Thank you I will ask this question in the chat room instead then and you can close it if need be! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Kit lenses are designed to be good value for money and versatile, and these days they achieve this pretty well and are a good way to start out. Especially if you value small size, the SEL-P1650 is absolutely awesome.

Sports photography is not really its forte, though. For that you ideally want a lens that is both long and fast, which by necessity means big, heavy and expensive. There are no such lenses for Sony E-mount, though many can be used via adapters.